# Can we fetch the file stored in the filestream through ssis script task?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, ssis, azure

I am trying to fetch the files from filestream using ssis script task and place the files in the destination folder , is their any standard approach to achieve this functionality .

Comment: why did you put azure and sql-azure as tag ?

Comment: Ya my filestream will be populated with data obtained from the azure containers , thats the reason i tagged it as azure, sorry for tagging under sql-azure

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;

using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
using System.Xml;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]

public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    //Initialize XML Document to read the XML file
    private XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();

    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();

        //Provide the path to read the XML file and load the xml document
        xDoc.Load(@"C:\XML Sample\Input.xml");

    }

    public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {
        //Iterate through each node which has the value "Employee" 
        // "//Employee" is the xpath to fetch all occurences of Employee node in the XML
        foreach (XmlNode xNode in xDoc.SelectNodes("//Employee"))
        {
            //Add new row to the output buffer for each employee node in the XML file
            this.EmployeeBuffer.AddRow();

            //Assign values to the columns.

            //Read the 1st attribute of the node Employee
            this.EmployeeBuffer.EmpID= xNode.Attributes[0].Value;

            //Read the 1st Child node of the node Employee
            this.EmployeeBuffer.Name= xNode.ChildNodes[0].InnerText;

            //Read the 2nd Child node of the node Employee
            this.EmployeeBuffer.Age= xNode.ChildNodes[1].InnerText;
        }
    }

    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();
    }
}
```